# Javascript onclick popup middle of browser not opening

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am unable to figure out why this javascript won't work. I am trying to make it open as a popup for a pinterest sharing button, but it continues to open as a tab, I've tried for over few hours. Any leads would be great as this seems to be a simple fix.

```
<a href="<?php echo 'http://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=' . $url . '&media=images/article_images/original/' . $article_image . '&description=' . $article_quote . ''; ?>" 
onClick="return pinterest_click(400, 300)" target="_blank" title="pinterest">0</a>

function pinterest_click(width, height)
{
    var leftPosition, topPosition;
    leftPosition = (window.screen.width / 2) - ((width / 2) + 10);
    topPosition = (window.screen.height / 2) - ((height / 2) + 50);
    var windowFeatures = "status=no,height=" + height + ",width=" + width + ",resizable=yes,left=" + leftPosition + ",top=" + topPosition + ",screenX=" + leftPosition + ",screenY=" + topPosition + ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no";
    u=location.href;
    media=<?php echo 'images/article_images/original/' .$article_image ?>;
    description=<?php echo $article_quote;?>;
    window.open('http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&media='+encodeURIComponent(media)+'&description='+encodeURIComponent(description),'sharer', windowFeatures);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is a corrected version of your function. You missed a couple of quotes in lines 'media=...' and 'description=...'.

```
function pinterest_click(width, height)
{
    var leftPosition, topPosition;
    leftPosition = (window.screen.width / 2) - ((width / 2) + 10);
    topPosition = (window.screen.height / 2) - ((height / 2) + 50);
    var windowFeatures = "status=no,height=" + height + ",width=" + width + ",resizable=yes,left=" + leftPosition + ",top=" + topPosition + ",screenX=" + leftPosition + ",screenY=" + topPosition + ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no";
    u=location.href;
    media="<?php echo 'images/article_images/original/' .$article_image ?>";
    description="<?php echo $article_quote;?>";
    window.open('http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&media='+encodeURIComponent(media)+'&description='+encodeURIComponent(description),'sharer', windowFeatures);
    return false;
}
```

Check out a working version at http://jsfiddle.net/7APYC/ .

Comment: Thank you, it was simple afterall!

Answer (score 0):

Try After removing `target="_blank"` from link...

Comment: No, that wouldn't have any effect on the problem, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine to me.

But I have a question and that is,

Why are you using anchor tag and adding the url in the href while you are already having the url in your javascript function.

I would suggest you to use a  or simply  and on it's click call your javascript function and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are writing the URL in the href attribute therefore your on click is not working.

Try

```
<a href="Javascript:;" onClick="return pinterest_click(400, 300)" target="_blank"  
title="pinterest">0</a>
```